# Optionally import Component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have several menu types and want to configure the type of menu to be used in .env.local for example: `VUE_APP_MENU_TYPE=2`

In my javascript file I have the following:

```
let menu = false;
if (process.env.VUE_APP_MENU_TYPE === "2") {
  menu = require("./type2/Type2.vue");
}
if (menu === false) {//default menu if env is missing
  menu = require("./default/Default.vue");
}
export default menu;
```

This will result in an error `Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

I can do the following:

```
import Default from "./default/Default.vue";
import Type2 from "./type2/Type2.vue";
let menu = Default;
if (process.env.VUE_APP_MENU_TYPE === "2") {
  menu = Type2;
}
export default menu;
```

This will work but all menus are compiled in the code, including menus that will never be used since VUE_APP_MENU_TYPE is known at compile time and will never change until you recompile.

Is it possible to import a component dynamically at compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `menu = require("./type2/Type2.vue").default;`

Explanation taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43249395/381282)

> when dealing with ES6 imports (`export default MyComponent`), the exported module is of the format `{"default" : MyComponent}`. The `import` statement correctly handles this assignment for you, however, you have to do the `require("./mycomponent").default` conversion yourself. If you want to avoid that, use `module.exports` instead of `export default`

Fort second part of question...

> Is it possible to import a component dynamically at compile time?

Really never tried but I have my doubts. Webpack is not executing the code when building. It just scans it for some patterns.

1. It scans for `require()` so it know what modules should be included in the bundle
2. [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) is replacing strings like `process.env.VUE_APP_MENU_TYPE` with values from `env` files so it make code look like `if ("3" === "2") {`
3. Other plugins are able to detect that `if ("3" === "2") {` is never `true` and eliminate "the death code"

Real question if what happens first - if `require` scanning happens before death code elimination, you will end up with all possible menu components in the bundle.  But unfortunately I don't know - You'l have to try

On the other hand using [dynamic async components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) (as mentioned in other answers) is sure bet. Yes, Webpack will build all possible menu components but each with it's own js chunk (js file in `dist` folder). If the app loads just one of them, it's seems fine to me (note that the loading will be async - at runtime - so it means one more server request)

Comment: I like the `require` way of doing this better than the alias webpack config so I'll go with that. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that loading the component dynamically is the best option you have.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think using those methods will have the components be part of the build. Say I have 20 different types of menus then all 20 are part of the build but I only need 1 and that's the one I already know about when I build. I'm looking for a way so the other 19 won't be part of the build.

Comment: I already load the component dynamically but I don't know how to build it dynamically. The way I got it working needs all components to be part of the build, even the ones that I'll never use for that build

Comment: Dynamic async components are not made part of the bundle. Yes they are compiled but each into its own separate JS chunk. So the files will be there in `dist` folder but if app never loads em who cares ?

Comment: @HMR the dynamic imports are packed into separate .chunk files, so the client won't load what's not needed.

Comment: @MichalLevý Thank you, so async would be another option to do this. It'll build the needless code but never loads it.

Answer (score 0):

I could have solved this with a webpack setting.

In vue.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        MENU: path.resolve(
          __dirname,
          (() => {
            if (process.env.VUE_APP_MENU_TYPE === "2") {
              return "src/components/header/CategoriesMenu/Type2/Type2.vue";
            }
            return "src/components/header/CategoriesMenu/Default/Default.vue";
          })()
        ),
      },
    },
  },
};
```

In src/components/header/CategoriesMenu/index.js

```
import menu from "MENU";
export default menu;
```

But to be honest, I like the `require` better.